# How can I write bash script that returns line from file which starts from the begining untill specific symbol?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have simple file:

```
line1(sometext)
line222(other_text)
line333(other text)
```

I pass to script in arguments part of word before symbol "("
How can I chech using grep command if this line exists ?
for example I pass in arguments word line222  - it returns line222(other_text)

but it I pass "line2" - it says that line was not found
Right now I have this code, that gives wrong result if I type one symbol

```
if ! grep home "myfile.txt" | grep -- "$1"; then
   echo "Line doesn't exist"
fi
```

Comment: You need to include your code ;-). Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: What do you need the `grep home` part for? `home` does not seem to occur in your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify whether the certain line exists or doesn't exist in your file as follows:

```
if [[ $(grep "^${1}" "myfile.txt") ]]; then
    echo "Line starts with \"${1}\" exists"
else
    echo "Line starts with \"${1}\" doesn't exist"
fi
```

or if you just want print the output info when it doesn't exist, then this may help:

```
if [[ ! $(grep "^${1}" "myfile.txt") ]]; then
    echo "Line starts with \"${1}\" doesn't exist"
fi
```

`grep "^${1}"` searches for the text pattern, `^${1}` means `starting with the variable` that you pass to your script. `[[ ... ]]` tests the condition (bash way) and `!` sign negates the test condition.